# Android app crashes on older phones

Tags: android, android-layout, crash

I recently published my first android game named "Freaky Fingers" on play store. Actually I used custom button shape from file named "home_button" to give outer border to my buttons.

```html
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_newgame"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/image_home"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/home_button"
        android:text="New Game"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        />
```

This app works perfectly on newer phone with Android 4+, but it crashes on Gingerbread 2.3.
The LogCat for the crash is given:-

```html
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{geekybytes.randomdots/randent.freakyfingers.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
 at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
 at randent.freakyfingers.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:19)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
 ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
 ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326)
 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:421)
 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
 ... 27 more
```

home_button.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#000000"
    android:endColor="#000000"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="3px" android:color="#FFC107" />
</shape>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove your `android:textAppearance` LOC.